# Netlify deploy failing with error: 'Input Error: You must pass a valid list of files to parse' during 'npm run build' command execution

Tags: npm, sass, package.json, netlify, astrojs

Description: [Click here for codebase on GitHub](https://github.com/chr1swill/https---github.com-chr1swill-astro-blog-website/issues/1)

Hello,
I am using Astro, SCSS, CSS, JavaScript and markdown for my static site. I am running into a problem when trying to deploy my site on Netlify. The deploy command 'npm run build' is failing with below error:

```
Input Error: You must pass a valid list of files to parse
build.command failed                                        
Error message
Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build
```

Here are the build-related scripts in my  `package.json` :

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "astro dev",
    "start": "astro dev npm-run-all copy --parallel watch serve",
    "build": "npm-run-all copy:html build:*",
    "preview": "astro preview",
    "astro": "astro",
    "build:sass": "sass  --no-source-map src/styles/sass:public/css",
    "copy:assets": "copyfiles -u 1 ./src/assets/**/* public",
    "copy:html": "copyfiles -u 1 ./src/*.html public",
    "copy": "npm-run-all --parallel copy:*",
    "watch:assets": "onchange \"/src/assets/**/*\" -- npm run copy:html",
    "watch:html": "onchange \"src/*.html\" -- npm run copy:html",
    "watch:sass": "sass  --no-source-map --watch src/styles/sass:src/styles",
    "watch": "npm-run-all --parallel watch:*",
    "serve": "browser-sync start --server public --files public",
    "start-sass": "npm-run-all copy --parallel watch serve",
    "build:astro": "astro build",
    "postbuild": "postcss public/css/*.css -u autoprefixer cssnano -r --no-map"
  }
}
```

### Troubleshooting Attempts

I've tried checking my scripts and file structure, and modifying build scripts, but with no success.

### Environment

- **Operating System:** Windows 10 Version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.3208)
- **Programming Language and Tools:** JavaScript, Node.js(v19.9.0), HTML, CSS, Markdown
- **Framework, Libraries, Preprocessors:** Astro and SCSS
- **Dependency Manager:** Node Package Manager(9.7.2)
- **Hardware Information:** Processor AMD Ryzen 5 3500U with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx 2.10 GHz, Installed RAM 8.00 GB (5.94 GB usable), System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Does anyone have any idea about this error and how it can be fixed? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

[Click here to check out my codebase on GitHub](https://github.com/chr1swill/https---github.com-chr1swill-astro-blog-website/issues/1)